# How to change sketch support in CATIA using vba?

Tags: vba, catia

I want to Change a sketch Support from one plane to another in macro.
I tried with StartCommand but that did not work. How can this be done without user Input?

I have tried the following code but it did not work.

```
 CATIA.StartCommand "Change Sketch Support"
 selection1.Add sketch3
 SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
 selection1.Add Plane_a
 SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
 part1.Update
```

Answer (score 1):

This link says to select the sketch then select the plane and run StartCommand "Change Sketch Support"

```
'Get the part object (Assume the part is open in it’s own window)
Set objPart = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Part

'Get the first sketch in the first geometrical set
Set objSketch = objPart.HybridBodies.Item(1).HybridSketches.Item(1)

'Get the plane called Plane.1 in the first geometrical set
Set objPlane = objPart.HybridBodies.Item(1).HybridShapes.Item(“Plane.1”)

'Select the sketch first then the new support plane
Set objSel = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
objSel.Clear
objSel.Add objSketch
objSel.Add objPlane

'Call the Change Sketch Support command
CATIA.StartCommand “Change Sketch Support”
```

https://v5vb.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/startcommand/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying by winapi and this is not the easiest way.
You have two alternatives:

Or you use copy and paste method

```
Dim osel As Selection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
osel.Clear()
osel.Add(sketch3)
osel.Copy()
osel.Clear()
osel.Add(Plane_a)
osel.Paste()
Dim RsltSketch As Sketch = osel.Item2(1).Value
osel.Clear()
'You can delete the first one if you want
osel.Add(sketch3)
osel.Delete()
```

Or you define the precise vectors

```
Dim arrayOfVariantOfDouble(8)
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(0) = OriginPointX
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(1) = OriginPointY
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(2) = OriginPointZ
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(3) = DirectionHorizontalX
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(4) = DirectionHorizontalY
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(5) = DirectionHorizontalZ
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(6) = DirectionVerticalX
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(7) = DirectionVerticalY
arrayOfVariantOfDouble(8) = DirectionVerticalZ
sketch3.SetAbsoluteAxisData(arrayOfVariantOfDouble)
```